# Extract user name from memory dump with windbg

Tags: windows, memory, dump, windbg

I would like to retrieve the name of the user that was signed in when the dump was created. Is that possible to do with windbg? I did some searching and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this command:

```
!envvar USERNAME
```

This reads the Environment-variable `username` which is filled by the system.

Comment: In case of a user mode dump and if the environment variable was not changed explicitly.